# How to get words per line and center text using GD Library?

Tags: php, gd

I need all words center in image with good margins, I use GD Library.

This code writes whatever you want over an image, the problem is not how to make what you write is centered at all times. The words are lowered and is not focused at all times on the image.

I have this code:

```
class textPainter{
private $img;
private $textColor;
private $position = array();
private $startPosition = array();

private $imagePath;
private $text;
private $fontFile;
private $fontSize;
private $format;

public function __construct($imagePath, $text, $fontFile, $fontSize){       
    $this->imagePath = $imagePath;
    $this->text = $text;
    $this->fontFile = $fontFile;
    $this->fontSize = $fontSize;

    $this->setFormat();
    $this->setQuality();
    $this->createImage();
    $this->setTextColor();
    $this->setPosition();
}

public function setTextColor($R=0, $G=0, $B=0){
    $this->textColor = imagecolorallocate ($this->img, $R, $G, $B);
}

public function show(){
    //show thumb
    header("Content-type: image/".$this->format);   
    //creates the text over the background image
    imagettftext($this->img, $this->fontSize, 0, $this->startPosition["x"], $this->startPosition["y"], $this->textColor, $this->fontFile, $this->text);

    switch ($this->format){
        case "JPEG":
            imagejpeg($this->img,"",$this->jpegQuality);
            break;
        case "PNG":
            imagepng($this->img);
            break;
        case "GIF":
            imagegif($this->img);
            break;
        case "WBMP":
            imagewbmp($this->img);
            break;
        default:
            imagepng($this->img);
    }
}

public function setQuality($value=85){
    $this->jpegQuality = $value;
}

public function setPosition($x="center", $y="center"){
    $this->position["x"] = $x;
    $this->position["y"] = $y;

    $dimensions = $this->getTextDimensions();

    if($x=="left"){
        $this->startPosition["x"] = 0;
    }
    else if($x=="center"){          
        $this->startPosition["x"] = imagesx($this->img)/2 - $dimensions["width"]/2;
    }
    else if($x=="right"){
        $this->startPosition["x"] = imagesx($this->img) - $dimensions["width"];
    }
    //custom
    else{
        $this->startPosition["x"] = $x;
    }

    if($y=="top"){
        $this->startPosition["y"] = 0 + $dimensions["heigh"];
    }
    else if($y=="center"){
        $this->startPosition["y"]  = imagesy($this->img)/2 + $dimensions["heigh"]/2;
    }
    else if($y=="bottom"){
        $this->startPosition["y"]  = imagesy($this->img);
    }
    //custom
    else{
        $this->startPosition["y"] = $y;
    }

}

private function setFormat(){
    $this->format = ereg_replace(".*\.(.*)$","\\1",$this->imagePath);
    $this->format = strtoupper($this->format);

    if($this->format=="JPG" || $this->format=="JPEG"){
        $this->format="JPEG";
    }
    else if($this->format=="PNG"){
        $this->format="PNG";
    }
    else if ($this->format=="GIF"){
        $this->format="GIF";
    }
    else if ($this->format=="WBMP"){
        $this->format="WBMP";
    }else{
        echo "Not Supported File";
        exit();
    }
}

private function createImage(){
    if($this->format=="JPEG"){
        $this->img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->imagePath);
    }
    else if($this->format=="PNG"){
        $this->img = imagecreatefrompng($this->imagePath);
    }
    else if ($this->format=="GIF"){
        $this->img = imagecreatefromgif($this->imagePath);
    }
    else if ($this->format="WBMP"){
        $this->img = imagecreatefromwbmp($this->imagePath);
    }else{
        echo "Not Supported File";
        exit();
    }
}

public function setFontFile($fontFile){
    $this->fontFile = $fontFile;

    //recalculate the text position depending on the new font file
    $this->setPosition($this->position["x"], $this->position["y"]);
}

public function setFontSize($fontSize){
    $this->fontSize = $fontSize;

    //recalculate the text position depending on the new font size
    $this->setPosition($this->position["x"], $this->position["y"]);
}

private function getTextDimensions(){
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox($this->fontSize, 0, $this->fontFile, $this->text);

    $minX = min(array($dimensions[0],$dimensions[2],$dimensions[4],$dimensions[6]));
    $maxX = max(array($dimensions[0],$dimensions[2],$dimensions[4],$dimensions[6]));

    $minY = min(array($dimensions[1],$dimensions[3],$dimensions[5],$dimensions[7]));
    $maxY = max(array($dimensions[1],$dimensions[3],$dimensions[5],$dimensions[7]));

    return array(
        'width' => $maxX - $minX,
        'heigh' => $maxY - $minY
    );
}  
}
```

And another:

```
    require_once 'class.textPainter.php';

$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];

$R = $_GET["r"];
$G = $_GET["g"];
$B = $_GET["b"];

$size = $_GET["size"];

$text = $_GET["text"];

$text = wordwrap($text, 20, "\n", false);

$img = new textPainter('sabiasBk.png', $text, 'Franklin.ttf', $size);

if(!empty($x) && !empty($y)){
    $img->setPosition($x, $y);
}

if(!empty($R) && !empty($G) && !empty($B)){
    $img->setTextColor($R,$G,$B);
}

$img->show();
```

With one line this works fine:

[image: With one line this works fine]

This is the fail:

[image: This is the fail]

Comment: May we see a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: I add two pictures with the fail

Comment: OK, much better. Is the problem that you want the text block in the second image to be vertically justified?

Comment: I want the text out focused on the image at all times.

Comment: I don't know what "focussed on the image" means - I think you mean vertical justification. Does your library allow you to get the height of the block of text before painting it?

Comment: Is [this class](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/blob/master/textPainter/class.textPainter.php) the one you're using? If so, try supplying `$y` as `center` to see if that does what you want.

Comment: Could you make a test with vertical justification ? I'm not sure if you allow what you say. Yes i use this class. Look i use this in code for show in page: `<img id="imgFinal" src="writingOverImage.php?x=center&y=center&size=20&text='.$_POST["text"].'" />`

Comment: I'm guessing here, but maybe `$img->setPosition()` - see the default values it uses - without parameters both axes will be set to `center`.

Comment: Can you set it in code?

Comment: Please try the solution I suggested above. I don't know what _exactly_ will work, so you need to experiment a bit.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be that method, since `getTextDimensions()` gets the text bounding box, and it is `private` so you're not meant to use that separately.

Comment: I try it, and not work :(  Can i send you all code with one zip?

Comment: No; I get the impression you want readers to work for free. You'll get help here, but not free work.

Comment: Okei, thanks for your help.